# Limit items on external list using BCS Filter

Tags: list, filter, sharepoint-2013, external, bcs

I have an external list which I want to filter without user input but try as I might I cannot see a solution??

In my list I have a series of names and an archive flag, I want to show the names in a picker where the archive flag is set to false which I thought would be simply a case of setting a default value on a filter but no matter what I do. The filter will not work unless there is a user added value

grateful for some advice as I am slowly going cuckoo

I am using on prem SP2013 with the BCS set to a SQL 2012 database

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the External Content Type from SharePoint designer you can assign a default static value and even create a more complex filter with variables. Be aware that if you are creating filters they can be wrong and you need to manually edit the *.ect file. I have an article in my blog about that, unfortunately it is in Swedish and about ODATA as the datasource, but the principle is the same. Perhaps Goog... translate is able to help you a bit on your way: https://itgeneralisten.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/sharepoint-hosted-app-odata-och-filter/